# Is it possible to encrypt a file so that it can't be edited, but still read by an .exe normally?

Tags: file, encryption, aes, public-key-encryption

i want to ask if someone know how to make encryption tool that encrypt a file , but still can read by an exe normally.

Example i have these .exe published already, and there is one file in folder that they can edit to make bugs. Can i encrypt it so that they can't edit it but read by the .exe normally?

I need to know what process should i do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: If a file can be written it can be edited.

Comment: if i make an encryption tool for it can it still be edited?

Comment: Yes.  If it is encrypted properly, it may be obvious that it has been edited/modified by someone who does not have the encryption key, but as long as it the medium it is stored on is writable, it can be overwritten.

Comment: I have one sample of encryption here that was made by a chinese guy, He made a dll file that connects the private key there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This appears to be a form of the obfuscation problem. There is no way to make it "un-editable", the best you can do is make it painful for someone to circumvent your obfuscation. You have to decide how much effort you want to put into your obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might be usable for your situation is to *sign* the file with a private key.  Then, your executable can have the public key and verify the signature of the file when it reads it.  That way, if any adversary modifies or edits the file, the signature will not match and the executable can reject the file.

This is still vulnerable if an adversary can modify the executable -- they can either remove the signature check, or replace the public key with their own key.

Comment: Can you tell me what should i search for it? or to where to find the source code.

Comment: I want to encryption a file and the private key will be in a dll file

Comment: Private keys never go in any dll or executable.  If they do, they cease to be private.  To be secure they must remain in a secure private key store.